# Is it possible to fill the table for five years using random data without tsql loops?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Task:
fill the table for 5 years randomly data: by weeks, month and years with some rates.
I solved this task by using 3 loops

```
WHILE @External_Loop_Counter <= @Total_Categories_Count
    BEGIN

    SET @Min_Amount = (SELECT T.AccountMin FROM 
    IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T WHERE TransactionID =
    @External_Loop_Counter)

    SET @Max_Amount = (SELECT T.AccountMax FROM 
    IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T WHERE TransactionID = 
    @External_Loop_Counter)

    SET @Check_Period = (SELECT T.Period  FROM 
    IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T WHERE T.TransactionID = 
    @External_Loop_Counter) 

    SET @Frequency_In_Period = (SELECT Rate FROM 
    IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T WHERE T.TransactionID = 
    @External_Loop_Counter)

    SET @Send_Rec_Acc = (SELECT AccountID FROM Marathon.dbo.Accounts LEFT 
    JOIN IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T ON AccountType = T.Account LEFT 
    JOIN Marathon.dbo.Categories ON OperationName = CategoryName WHERE 
    CategoryID = @External_Loop_Counter)

    SET @Choose_Send_Rec = (SELECT CASE
    WHEN (SELECT TransactionType FROM (SELECT * FROM 
    IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T FULL JOIN Marathon.dbo.Categories C 
    ON C.CategoryName = T.OperationName) X WHERE CategoryID = 
    @External_Loop_Counter) = 'Exp' THEN @Send_Rec_Acc

    WHEN (
        SELECT TransactionType FROM (
           SELECT * FROM IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T 
           FULL JOIN Marathon.dbo.Categories C 
           ON C.CategoryName = T.OperationName) X WHERE CategoryID = 
           @External_Loop_Counter) = 'Inc' THEN NULL
    END)

    SET @Choose_Send_Rec1 = (SELECT CASE
    WHEN (
        SELECT TransactionType FROM (
            SELECT * FROM IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T FULL JOIN 
             Marathon.dbo.Categories C ON C.CategoryName = T.OperationName) X 
        WHERE CategoryID = @External_Loop_Counter) = 'Exp' THEN NULL
    WHEN (
        SELECT TransactionType FROM (
            SELECT * FROM IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T FULL JOIN 
            Marathon.dbo.Categories C ON C.CategoryName = T.OperationName) X 
        WHERE CategoryID = @External_Loop_Counter) = 'Inc' THEN @Send_Rec_Acc
     END)

     SET @Jump_Ratio = (
        CASE
            WHEN @Check_Period = 'Week' THEN @Week_T
            WHEN @Check_Period = 'Month' THEN @Month_T
            WHEN @Check_Period = 'Year' THEN @Year_T
        END)

SET @TempDayCounter = @Jump_Ratio
    WHILE @TempDayCounter <= @Total_Dates
        BEGIN
            SET @Rate_Counter = 1
                WHILE @Rate_Counter <= @Frequency_In_Period
                    BEGIN                        
                        INSERT INTO Marathon.dbo.Transactions (TransactionDate, TransactionAmount, CategoryID, SendingAccount, RecipientAccount)
                        VALUES((SELECT RateDate FROM IntermediateM.dbo.Rates WHERE RateID = CEILING(@TempDayCounter*RAND())), (@Max_Amount - CAST(((@Max_Amount - @Min_Amount)) AS FLOAT)*RAND()),
                        (SELECT CategoryID FROM (SELECT * FROM IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T FULL JOIN Marathon.dbo.Categories C ON C.CategoryName = T.OperationName WHERE TransactionID = @External_Loop_Counter) X ),
                 @Choose_Send_Rec, @Choose_Send_Rec1)
                       SET @Rate_Counter = @Rate_Counter + 1
                    END
                    SET @TempDayCounter = @TempDayCounter + @Jump_Ratio
         END
         SET @External_Loop_Counter = @External_Loop_Counter + 1
   END
END
```

My question is: can I solve this WITHOUT loops?
If it's possible - please take me advice how to do this.
I think it's possible but the query would the very huge with different WHERE and HAVING
Here are DDL and data
    [init main DB](http://dropmefiles.com/6JrD7)
    [fill main DB](http://dropmefiles.com/YsfOP)
    [data for rates](http://dropmefiles.com/gsSAf)
    [data for transactions](http://dropmefiles.com/bupDK)
    [output](http://dropmefiles.com/VxLU3)

Comment: You're gong to need to be a little more specific that this. We can't run your SQL, so we can't see the output. This could be likely be a candidate for CTE or recursive CTE, however, I'm not going to guess an answer. If you edit your post to include some DDL, Sample data and expected output(s) it would really help you get some answers.

Comment: Some of your variables are just declared but no values are assigned. can you provide some sample input? Also the table design

Comment: 5 years worth of weeks is only 260 rows; query some other table int he database with more than 260 rows and make liberal use of random functions to generate random data for 5 years. You don't have to use any of the existing data, youre just simply looking for a way to create 260 arbitrary rows (actually, you don't even need a table for this, you can use a CTE.. it's just easier for a sql newbie to use a table). if you want another 65 rows you can either query a table that has more than 325 rows, or you can sum/aggregate the week data if the months and years data has to relate to the weeks data

Comment: After inserting all data in my table, the table consists over 1800 fields, not 260

Comment: Google 'tally table' to find out all the ways to generate rows without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an answer. It's only an advice how to do it little shorter.
You can use

```
SELECT
    @Min_Amount = AccountMin,
    @Max_Amount = AccountMax,
    @Check_Period = ,
    @Frequency_In_Period = Rate,
    @Jump_Ratio =
        CASE Period
            WHEN 'Week' THEN @Week_T
            WHEN 'Month' THEN @Month_T
            WHEN 'Year' THEN @Year_T
        END
FROM IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions
WHERE TransactionID = @External_Loop_Counter
```

instead four queries

```
SET @Min_Amount = (SELECT T.AccountMin FROM 
IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T WHERE TransactionID = 
@External_Loop_Counter)

SET @Max_Amount = (SELECT T.AccountMax FROM 
IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T WHERE TransactionID = 
@External_Loop_Counter)

SET @Check_Period = (SELECT T.Period  FROM 
IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T WHERE T.TransactionID = 
@External_Loop_Counter)         

SET @Frequency_In_Period = (SELECT Rate FROM 
IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T WHERE T.TransactionID = 
@External_Loop_Counter)
```

and

```
 SET @Jump_Ratio = (
    CASE
        WHEN @Check_Period = 'Week' THEN @Week_T
        WHEN @Check_Period = 'Month' THEN @Month_T
        WHEN @Check_Period = 'Year' THEN @Year_T
    END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've analyzed and modified your query as below to reduce the loops from 3 to 1.

```
WHILE @External_Loop_Counter <= @Total_Categories_Count
BEGIN

    SELECT
        @Min_Amount = T.AccountMin,
        @Max_Amount = T.AccountMax,
        @Check_Period = T.Period,
        @Frequency_In_Period = Rate,
        @Send_Rec_Acc = AccountID,
        @Choose_Send_Rec = CASE WHEN EXISTS
                            (
                                SELECT 1 FROM IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T 
                                    FULL JOIN Marathon.dbo.Categories C 
                                        ON C.CategoryName = T.OperationName
                                            WHERE CategoryID = T.TransactionID
                                                AND TransactionType = 'Exp'
                            )THEN @Send_Rec_Acc END,
        @CategoryID = CategoryID--Added New Variable @CategoryID
        FROM IntermediateM.dbo.Transactions T 
            WHERE TransactionID = @External_Loop_Counter

    SELECT 
        @Choose_Send_Rec1 = CASE WHEN @Choose_Send_Rec IS NULL
                                    THEN @Send_Rec_Acc END,
        @Jump_Ratio = CASE
                        WHEN @Check_Period = 'Week' THEN @Week_T
                        WHEN @Check_Period = 'Month' THEN @Month_T
                        WHEN @Check_Period = 'Year' THEN @Year_T
                        END

    SET @TempDayCounter = @Jump_Ratio

    WITH TempCounter
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            TempDayCounter = @TempDayCounter

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            TempDayCounter = TempDayCounter+@Jump_Ratio
            FROM TempCounter 
                WHERE TempDayCounter<= @Total_Dates
    ) ,CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT
            SeqNo = 1,
            TempDayCounter = CEILING(TempDayCounter*RAND())
            FROM TempCounter

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            SeqNo = SeqNo+1,
            TempDayCounter = CEILING(TempDayCounter*RAND())
            FROM CTE
                WHERE SeqNo <= @Frequency_In_Period
    )
    INSERT INTO Marathon.dbo.Transactions (TransactionDate, TransactionAmount, CategoryID, SendingAccount, RecipientAccount)
    SELECT 
        RateDate,
        @Max_Amount - CAST(((@Max_Amount - @Min_Amount)) AS FLOAT)*RAND(),
        @CategoryID,
        @Choose_Send_Rec, 
        @Choose_Send_Rec1
        FROM IntermediateM.dbo.Rates R
            WHERE EXISTS
            (
                SELECT
                    1
                    FROM CTE
                        WHERE TempDayCounter = R.RateID
            )

END
```

I was not able to use your scripts provided above so, not able to test the query completly. but beleive this will work.Let me know otherwise

Comment: When I've tried to launch I get error 102 '='                                                                       Somewhere in loop I lose equal sign

Comment: are you running it in ssms or any 3rd pary tool ?

Comment: I use DBeaver GUI for mssql

Comment: try executing it in ssms if possible, else google for the error message you got. I've never seen this in SSMS

Comment: It will be very problematic because I use Ubuntu. I don't know if exists any version of SSMS on Linux. And one more question. May I ask?

Comment: Microsoft has launched SQL server for Linux. So there will be SSMS available for Linux

Comment: My another question is: how I can count summary for the everyweek period by the year?